# An easy way to write INSERT INTO table VALUES (value1, value2, ...valueN)

Tags: php, database, postgresql, insert

I need to insert values from an array using PHP into my database. The array has 40 positions, each position is a value I have to insert into a table of my database.

I need a quick way to write it down and not write `$1,$2,$3 ... $39`

I tried:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES($1,$2, ..... $39)';
$result = pg_query_params($dbh, $s, $a[0]); //$a[0] array with 39 positions
```

But it's too long to write it down. I have another piece of code where I have 140 positions.

Comment: Not clear on the structure of your array or the table you are trying to insert to.

Comment: Why the hell do you have respectively 40 and 140 columns in your tables ? Each column should have its own semantic. Is there really a good reason for having so many columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build an array range from 1 to the length of the array and add the `$` and commas:

```
$values = '$' . implode(',$', range(1, count($array)));
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES($values)";
$result = pg_query_params($dbh, $query, $array);
```

Comment: thank you for your help!! I was exactly what I needed.